# What does it mean to "permute" a predictor in the context of random forest?

Tags: random-forest, cart, permutation

I am reading the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/randomForestExplainer/vignettes/randomForestExplainer.html) for the R package randomForestExplainer.

There the result `accuracy_decrease (classification)` is defined as

> mean decrease of prediction accuracy after X_j is permuted

What does it mean "permuted" in this context? How is a predictor variable "permuted"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sample *without* replacement, i.e. we get a scrambled/"permuted" version of $x_j$.